# Cron - setting range of time

Tags: triggers, cron

How set time by cron to run cron job every 10 minutes from for example 8:10 am to 13:50 pm? I don't know how set range of time with minutes... For time from 8:00 am to 14:00 pm it would be
*/1 8-14 * * * 
but how to add this minutes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cron expression for a time range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282036/cron-expression-for-a-time-range)

Answer (score 0):

Your cron entry should be similar to

```
*/10 8-13 * * * /path/to/your/script
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not helpful. My problem is how to define this minutes that job start from 8:10 am and ends 13:50 pm.