# Schedule Job for specific hours interval using Quartz

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler, jobs

My Quartz cron expression is this:

```
50 * 10-11 * * ?
```

From what I understand this means:

> Run the job every 50 second of every minute within hours 10 to 11 (am) for every week/month and year.

The problem is that the job is running even after hour 11AM..

I tried

```
50 * 10-11 * * *
```

but this way I get the exception:

```
support for specifying both a day-of-week and a day-of-month parameter is not implemented
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cron expression for a time range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282036/cron-expression-for-a-time-range)

Comment: Hi, I am asking a specific question in this case. I think I have made it clear what works and how it works. It is not working as it should, so please help me if you have any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how it works. 10-11 actually means that the job will run for 2 hours and not for one. It will run till 11:59:59. The same thing is even for minutes; if I write:

> 50 0-10 10-11 * * ?

The job will run on second 50 for 11 times(0-10) for each hour (10 and 11).

Hope this will help someone like me :)