# how to write a complex quartz cron expression

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

i need to develop a web service, that will help the client to do some periodic job, the api will like this 
void Dojob(int jobType, string cronExpression);

because the client/user will do anything the want, i just want to know does the cron expression support the situation below:

the job will fire in the following times:
from 9:10am to 10:50am trigger at every 8 minutes, every day.

from 9:00 to 10:00 maybe easier, but i still cannot find the correct cron Expression about 9:10am to 10:50am.

Comment: what did you try ? What is preventing you from achieving that ?

Comment: that's a example. the time duration, frequency and timing of the task is depend on the users. Users can set their own trigger. i am not sure cron can support this.

Comment: It can support this perfectly fine.

Comment: i need to develop a web service, that will help the client to do some periodic job, the api will like this Dojob(int jobType, string cronExpression). i just want to know does the cron expression support the situation above.

Comment: Read this tutorial to get a feel of what quartz does support: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger . Yes it does support scheduling as you asked for, there are even close examples in that tutorial.

Comment: thank you, and i checked the doc for a long time, and still cannot get the answer. from 9:00 to 10:00 is easy, but 9:10 to 10:50 is not.

Comment: - - used to specify ranges. / - used to specify increments. Check this answer also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282036/cron-expression-for-a-time-range

Comment: thanks a lot, it is a good idea to separate to several cron expression. but my question above, "every 8 minutes",  8 is not the common divisor of 60, that is the tricky. i think maybe i should limit the client, this kind of requirement is not supported. :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can do this using one cron expression, but you can using two.

eg

```
0 10,18,26,34,42,50,58 9 1/1 * ? *

0 6,14,22,30,38,46 10 1/1 * ? *
```

Answer (score 1):

As sgmoore said, you cannot do this using 1 cron expression. You'll have to create 2 triggers each with different cron expressions to get this to work.

The first will be from 9:10 to 9:59 every 8 minutes which looks like this:

```
0 10-59/8 9 1/1 * ? *
```

The second will be from 10:00 to 10:50 every 8 minutes which looks like this:

```
0 0-50/8 10 1/1 * ? *
```

Just be warned that due to how cron expressions work, this will fire every 8 minutes restarting at the top of every hour, therefore firing at both 9:58 and 10:00 in this scenario